# Trying to redefine the tensor gradient function for rounding in theano

Tags: gradient, theano

I am trying find a gradient of a variable, but because I rounded the variable before hand, theano's gradient function registers the gradient as 0 (since rounding is a discontinuous function). For example,

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

x = T.scalar()
y = T.round(x)**2

dy = T.grad(y, x)

df = theano.function(inputs=[x],outputs = dy)

print(df(3))
```

returns 0.0 but I want it to return 2x.

Is there a way to make the gradient of T.round(x) to act like x?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it wouldn't calculate ("register"?) the gradient as zero if the function had a discontinuous domain: rather, the gradient would be undefined (can't differentiate over a discontinuous domain).

Why would you want to calculate a gradient of a rounded variable?  Think about what (if any) geometric sense this putative "gradient" makes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. True, the gradient should be undefined, but I guess theano defines it as zero for some reason. 

I want to round the variables as I am trying to study the effect of quantization (e.g. representing a 64bit value but rounded to 48bits) has on the performance of a NN. I felt that quantizing the variables shouldn't alter the characteristics of the gradient and thus I am trying to artificially make it act as if it was not rounded.

Comment: For more on the quantizing. I am essentially doing `x_quantized = T.round(x*2**n)/2**n` where n is the bit resolution.